# python md5, d.update(strParam).hexdigest() returns NoneType.=, why?

Tags: python, md5

```
>>> d = md5.new()
>>> d.update('a').hexdigest()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'
```

this would work -

```
>>> d = md5.new()
>>> d.update('a')
>>> d.hexdigest()
'0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661'
```

is there an explanation on shortening python code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this:

```
import hashlib
hashlib.md5('a').hexdigest()
```

Note: Don't use plain MD5 for security.

- If you're hashing passwords, use scrypt or bcrypt.
- If you're authenticating a message, use an HMAC.
- If you're checking file integrity, consider SHA2 or newer.

Answer (score 6):

You can just do:

```
md5.new('a').hexdigest()
```

Paraphrased from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/md5.html#md5.new):

> `new(arg)` returns a new md5 object. If `arg`
>   is present, the method call
>   `update(arg)` is made.

---

But `md5` is deprecated.
Use `hashlib` instead.

Edit:
There are also issues with `md5` so depending on your purposes you might want to use a more-secure hash function, e.g. SHA-256:

```
import hashlib
hashlib.sha256('a').hexdigest()
```

Note that SHA-256 will take longer to compute so if you have time restrictions this may not be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since update had "no" return (default return in Python = None), calling `update(arg).<anything>` has to fail. Sometimes libraries will have `return self` as their last line of a method. If that were the case here, your first code sample would work.

With a semi-colon you can put all of your code on one line:

```
d = md5.new(); d.update('a'); d.hexdigest()
```

But it is generally discouraged.

Comment: "If you want to put all of that on one line" DON'T. DO. THAT.

Comment: @Franklin There is a reason it is a part of the language -- Von Rossum believe there to be a use case, so there might be a use case.

Comment: @Franklin Well, Von Rossum thought that there was. Since my choice is between you and the man who created the language, I'll have to go with the author of the language.

Comment: GvR is not always right... People inherit bad programming habits from other languages. [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says to not use write that way.

Comment: @Franklin Well then. I was not aware of that. Answer amended.

Comment: it's actually possible to put most code on a single line without using semicolons. it's usually ugly :)